# How would I structure this database to achieve functionality?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to create a plugin with WP and I'm having some trouble figuring out how I want to structure the database. My project consists of a few main points and the part I'm stuck on is having the DB interact where users can join "projects". Users would be able to create, join (biggest part I'm having trouble on), and delete a "project" if they wanted to. The DB schema I was considering was something like:

```
projects_db
 id
 name
 description
 other fields describing date created, created by, etc.
```

How would I either implement **more fields** or **create another DB** to handle joined users to the "project"?
Thank you!

Comment: SO questions are for issues with your code.  Design questions should go into http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically trying to implement an N:M relationship between `users` and `projects`. The classic solution for this is to have a mapping table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_projects (
    user_id INT,
    project_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, project_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES projects(id)
)
```

EDIT:
To elaborate on the comment, having a use join a project would simply be an insert to this table. E.g., if user 1 is joining project 345:

```
INSERT INTO user_projects VALUES (1, 345)
```

To query which users have joined a project, you could use a `join`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users u
JOIN   user_projects up ON u.id = up.user_id
WHERE  up.project_id = 345
```

Or if you want to search according to some other details of the project, like, e.g. its name, you could just join that table too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users u
JOIN   user_projects up ON u.id = up.user_id
JOIN   projects p ON up.project_id = p.id
WHERE  p.project_name = 'my_project'
```

Comment: So if a user wanted to join a project, they hit a button, a query goes through, would it look something like:


INSERT user_projects ( userid -> my user id, projectid -> project_im_joining)

And to view users contributing to a project it would just be a simple SELECT command?

Comment: @drinkingCube yup, pretty much. And if you'd want the full details on the user/project, just use a join.

Comment: could you clarify "just use a join"?

Comment: @drinkingCube I've edited my post. If that doesn't answer your question, please clarify what you'd still like be to elaborate on.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much for the clear and concise answers, I think I understand everything and I'll attempt to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table which would store informations about users belonging to specific projects. Consider a table:

```
project_users
  fk_user_id
  fk_project_id
  (possibly date joined here etc)
```

Now, it is very easy to add/remove info about new users. Hope this helps!